# Amazon Web Services : Create a stream between two mobile devices

Tags: android, ios, sockets, amazon-web-services, streaming

I know I can set this up on EC2 with a service that I build and deploy on my webserver, but is there an Amazon component that allows low latency streaming between two mobile devices ?

I need to send very low latency messages between two (online and in-app) mobile devices in a stream like scenario for which SNS is of course not suitable.

Comment: Absolutely no reason for a down vote on this. A legitimate question.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no AWS service to communicate between mobile devices.

To implement your use case I would have a look at MQTT. This is a device to device messaging protocol. Designed with mobile in mind (unreliable or high latency networks). It is originally from IBM. But it has been open sourced and many implementations are available for all major platforms. http://mqtt.org